# Calling terraform plan/apply from C#

Tags: c#, terraform

I am building a ASP.NET application where I need to implement a feature when user clicks a button, I need to trigger a terraform plan and apply. I already have the terraform templates ready. What is the best way to do it? Right now, I am using terraform enterprise which allows me to upload the terraform template to the TF cloud, create a configuration version, create a run, and the deployment runs on TF cloud, all via separate REST API calls. It works, but I don't know if that's the right way. Is it ok to call the terraform command as a separate process from the ASP.NET application like below?

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "terraform.exe";
```

and pass arguments for plan/apply. The only problem I am facing with TF enterprise is that it allows only one run at a time. I need to pay more for concurrent runs. I believe the above approach would solve this issue. Any inputs on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tfe.NetClient which is a .NET Client for Terraform Enterprise.
https://github.com/everis-technology/Tfe.NetClient

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This .netclient is basically a wrapper around the enterprise REST API. Since I am already using the REST API, I don't think this would be very useful for me.